# PostgreSQLで特定のテーブルJOINのみエラーが出る

Tags: go, postgresql, gorm

PostgreSQLで特定のテーブルJOINのみエラーが出る

Go言語とPostgreSQLでAPIサーバーを開発しています。

その際、userテーブル をJOIN使用とした時のみ、以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

questionテーブルを起点にanswer、trip,userをJOINするSELECT文を書いています。

```
{
    "Severity": "ERROR",
    "Code": "42601",
    "Message": "syntax error at or near \".\"",
    "Detail": "",
    "Hint": "",
    "Position": "76",
    "InternalPosition": "",
    "InternalQuery": "",
    "Where": "",
    "Schema": "",
    "Table": "",
    "Column": "",
    "DataTypeName": "",
    "Constraint": "",
    "File": "scan.l",
    "Line": "1149",
    "Routine": "scanner_yyerror"
}
```

ソースコードはGORMで以下のようなものを書いています。

```
func GetQuestionDetail(c *gin.Context) {
    id, err := strconv.Atoi(c.Param("id"))
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
    }
    type Result struct {
        models.Question
        models.Answer
        Id int64 `json:"question_id" db:"id"`
        Title       string    `json:"title" db:"title"`
        PictureUrls string    `json:"picture_urls" db:"picture_urls"`
        Description string    `json:"description" db:"description"`
        Start       time.Time `json:"start" db:"start"`
        PostUserID  int64     `json:"post_user_id" db:"user_id"`
        AnswerUserName string `json:"answer_user_name" db:"name"`
    }
    var result []Result
    if err := config.DB.Table("question").Select("question.*, question.id AS question_id, trip.*, answer.trip_id, user.* ").
        Joins("left outer join answer on answer.question_id = question.id").
        Joins("join trip on trip.trip_id = answer.trip_id").
        Joins("join user on user.user_id = answer.user_id").
        Where("question.id = ?", id).Scan(&result).Error; err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
    } else {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, result)
    }
}
```

テーブル構造

**user**

```
-- Table Definition ----------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE "user" (
    user_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name text NOT NULL,
    about text NOT NULL,
    picture_url text NOT NULL,
    email text NOT NULL UNIQUE CHECK (email <> ''::text),
    password text NOT NULL CHECK (password <> ''::text),
    role smallint NOT NULL CHECK (role > 0),
    location text,
    born text NOT NULL,
    familiar text NOT NULL,
    skills text NOT NULL,
    background_url text NOT NULL,
    sns_url text,
    birth smallint,
    languages text NOT NULL,
    gender text,
    timezone text
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_email_key ON "user"(email text_ops);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_pkey ON "user"(user_id int8_ops);
```

**question**

```
-- Table Definition ----------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE question (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at timestamp with time zone,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone,
    deleted_at timestamp with time zone,
    user_id bigint,
    body text
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX question_pkey ON question(id int4_ops);
CREATE INDEX idx_question_deleted_at ON question(deleted_at timestamptz_ops);
```

**answer**

```
-- Table Definition ----------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE answer (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at timestamp with time zone,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone,
    deleted_at timestamp with time zone,
    question_id bigint,
    user_id bigint,
    trip_id bigint
);

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX answer_pkey ON answer(id int4_ops);
CREATE INDEX idx_answer_deleted_at ON answer(deleted_at timestamptz_ops);
```

**trip**

```
-- Table Definition ----------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE trip (
    trip_id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    title text NOT NULL CHECK (title <> ''::text),
    description text NOT NULL,
    notes text NOT NULL,
    min_participants integer NOT NULL,
    max_participants integer NOT NULL,
    price_per_person real NOT NULL CHECK (price_per_person >= 0::double precision),
    currency character varying(3) NOT NULL CHECK (currency::text <> ''::text),
    picture_urls text[] NOT NULL,
    user_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES "user"(user_id),
    public boolean NOT NULL,
    featured boolean NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    start timestamp with time zone,
    included bytea,
    with_who integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    kind integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    language integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    CONSTRAINT trip_check CHECK (min_participants >= 0 AND min_participants <= max_participants),
    CONSTRAINT trip_check1 CHECK (max_participants >= 0 AND max_participants >= min_participants)
);
COMMENT ON COLUMN trip.with_who IS '0:未選択, 1:カップル・夫婦, 2:家族, 3:一人, 4:友達';
COMMENT ON COLUMN trip.kind IS '0:未選択, 1:デート, 2:プロポーズ, 3:新婚旅行';
COMMENT ON COLUMN trip.language IS '1:日本語   2:日本語以外';

-- Indices -------------------------------------------------------

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX trip_pkey ON trip(trip_id int8_ops);
```

GORMでデバッグを行った際に、表示されるSQL文を直接コマンドで実行しても同じエラーが出るので、PostgreSQLの問題ではないかと思います。

```
 SELECT question.*, question.id AS question_id, trip.*, answer.trip_id, user.*  FROM "question" left outer join answer on answer.question_id = question.id join trip on trip.trip_id = answer.trip_id join user on user.user_id = answer.user_id WHERE (question.id = 3)
```

エラーメッセージの意味がわからず困っているので、お助けください。

バージョン情報
Go : 1.14.1
PostgreSQL : 12.2

Comment: `user`はSQLでは予約後ですから、生成されたSQL内で`user`と引用符なしで参照している部分が構文エラーになっているようです。GORMの部分はよくわからないのですが、`user`の部分全てを(DDLと同様に)`"user"`とするSQLが生成されるよう部分SQLを記載している文字定数を修正すれば動くようにできそうに思われます。ただ、今後同様のトラブルを避けたいなら、`user`と言うテーブル名は変更してしまった方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: harry0000のおっしゃる通りでした。

Comment: postgreSQLを使い慣れていなかったため、大変助かりました。誠にありがとうございます。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。標準SQL的にはダメなSQLが動いているように見えちゃうDBMSは、ちょくちょくあるので、なかなか難しいところです。具体的にどのように対応されて解決したのか、自己回答として投稿していただけると、今後似たような問題に苦しんでこのサイトを訪れた人の助けになるだろうと思います。お時間を取らせることになりますが、是非ご検討下さい。

Comment: OOperさんご丁寧にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

userがPostgreSQLの予約語だったため、以下のようにバッククオーテーションを使って、userテーブル名がダブルクオーテーションで囲われるように改良しました。

```
if err := config.DB.Table("question").Select(`question.*, question.created_at AS question_created_at, trip.*, answer.trip_id AS answer_trip_id,
        "qu".name AS question_user_name, "qu".picture_url AS question_user_image,
        "au".name AS answer_user_name, "au".picture_url AS answer_user_image
    `).
    Joins("left join answer on answer.question_id = question.id").
    Joins("left join trip on trip.trip_id = answer.trip_id").
    Joins(`left join "user" AS au ON "au"."user_id" = answer.user_id`).
    Joins(`left join "user" AS qu ON question.user_id = "qu"."user_id"`).
    Where("question.id = ?", id).Scan(&result).Error; err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, err)
} else {
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, result)
}
```